# How to disable ng-show from directive in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive to find out when the image is loaded. In my view, I have a `span` that has a loading spinner and will be displayed by `ng-show`. The default value is **TRUE**.

```
<ion-spinner icon="android" ng-show="showSpinner"></ion-spinner>
<img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" imageonload>
```

directive:

```
.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                /* HOW TO DISABLE showSpinner */
            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('error.');
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to control a component which is outside your directive from inside your directive ?

Comment: @Yasser What do you exactly mean by `controlling a component` ?

Comment: you can emit an event in your load callback, then handle this event int the parent controller (where you have showSpinner variable declared)

Comment: show/hide in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account, you haven't specified `scope` attribute when defining your directive, that means no scope is created for the directive and the directive uses its parent's scope, so you can just do the following:

```
element.bind('load', function() {
    scope.showSpinner = false;
});
```

More over, [`scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) should be used, because you're handling DOM events that are out of the Angular JS life cycle:

```
element.bind('load', function() {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.showSpinner = false;
    });
});
```

But it should be tested.

Comment: @vahidnajafi Cool :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use a $broadcast and $on to broacast the information from the directive to the controller

in directive:

```
scope.$broadcast('stopSpinner');
```

in controller:

```
$scope.$on('stopSpinner',function() {scope.showSpinner = false});
```

U will maybe need to use rootscope instead of scope

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showSpinner = true;
});

app.directive('imageonload', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            showSpinner: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //emulate the delay to load an image, in the reality this line MUST be removed
            $timeout(function(){ scope.showSpinner = false; }, 1000);

            element.bind('load', function() {
                /* HOW TO DISABLE showSpinner */
                scope.showSpinner = false;
            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('error.');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-show="showSpinner">Loading...</div>
    <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" imageonload show-spinner="showSpinner">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.